# Store each partition to file and load it on same partition in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, io, filereader, partition

I have situation where have to store each partition's data to a file and load stored data at same partition later. Here is my code

Base class

```
case class foo ( posVals : Array[Double] , velVals : Array[Double] , f:  Array[Double] =>  Double ,
               fitnessVal: Double , LR1 : Double  , PR1 : Double) extends Serializable  {
 var position      : Array[Double]          =     posVals 
 var velocity      : Array[Double]          =     velVals 
 var fitness       : Double                 =     fitnessVal
 var PulseRate: Double = PR1
 var LoudnessRate: Double = LR1
}
```

Objective function

```
def sphere (ar : Array[Double]) : Double = ar.reduce((x,y) => x+y*y)
```

Store and read data inside each partition

```
def execute(RDD: RDD[foo], c_itr: Int  ): Array[(foo, Int)] = {
val newRDD = RDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex {
  (index, Iterator) => {
    var arr: Array[foo] = Iterator.toArray
    if (c_itr != 0) {
      //Read Data from stored file where file name is equal to partition number (index)
      val bufferedSource = Source.fromFile("/result/"+index+".txt")
      val lines = bufferedSource.getLines()
      val data : Array[BAT1] = lines.flatMap{line =>
       val p = line.split(",")
       Seq( BAT1(p(0).toArray.map(_.toDouble) , p(1).toArray.map(_.toDouble) ,sphere ,line(2).toDouble, p(3).toDouble,    p(4).toDouble)  )
      }.toArray
     }

     arr = data.clone() // Replace arr with loaded data from file


      //Save to file
    val writer = new FileWriter(Path + index + ".txt")
    for (  i  <-  0  until  arr.length    ) {
      writer.write(arr(i).position.toList + "," + arr(i).velocity.toList + "," + arr(i).fitness + "," +
        arr(i).LoudnessRate + "," + arr(i).PulseRate + "\n")
    }
    writer.close()
    val bests : Array[(foo , Int)] = res1.map(x => (x, index))
    bests.toIterator
   }
 }
 newRDD.persist().collect()
}
```

Sample of data stored in file is.

```
 List(86.6582767815429, -25.224569272200586, 90.52371028878218, -59.91851894060545, -37.12944037124118),List(-59.60155033146984, -8.927455672466586, -23.679516503590534, 87.58857469881022 ,-14.864361504195127),6.840659702736215E10,0.6012,0.04131580765457621
 List(86.6582767815429, -25.224569272200586, 90.52371028878218, -59.91851894060545, -26.10553311409422),List(-66.83980088207335, 51.088426986986015, -109.74073303298485, 66.87095748811572, -22.941448024344268),9.195157603574039E10,0.9025,0.06132589765454988
```

This code is not reading exact data when data is read from file. I tried lot but unable to find the issue. How can I read stored data correctly in **data** object ?

Comment: what is value of `RDD` that you are passing in `execute` ?

Comment: RDD of type foo

Comment: That i understand, but i am asking about the value present in it. `mapPartitionsWithIndex` will go through each partition present in your RDD. My question what is the data present in RDD, are you reading from somewhere? or generating it?

Comment: Generating. Please look at line after save to file comment. Writer is writing data to file and data is loaded